# Visual C++ .NET using C# library. Need help?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

I have a library a friend wrote in C# and I need to use it in C++.NET. I'm new to VC++.NET and I don't know how to declare my class so it can be used by all functions in my file.. Here's my code..

```
using namespace System;
using namespace ONEAPI;
namespace Bot{

    void InitializeBot();
    ONEAPI::Connection connection(true);
    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {
        Console::BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor::Black;
        InitializeBot();
        return 0;
    }
    void InitializeBot(){
        connection.StartConnection("127.0.0.1", 1274, "username",
            "B73955EE7A30E959819BAE2392F6F4441DF98C66A4026EF55287A81D1F815504",
            "R0Bo");
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error  1  error C3145: 'connection' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'ONEAPI::Connection'  Visual Studio 2010\Projects\1hubBot\1hubBot\1hubBot.cpp  10  1  1hubBot

Comment: In future please just put the text in the question, rather than using Pastie. I've edited it in for you this time...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to use the code thing.

Comment: @Troy: All you have to do is paste in the code, select it all, and click the "code format" button in the toolbar. It looks like a pair of curly braces: `{}`. All it's doing is indenting each line with 4 spaces--that's what the formatting engine uses to detect code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a managed type ("Connection") within a static or global - it has to exist inside of a `ref class` or as a local.  This is a requirement of C++/CLI.

You'll need to put your code into a managed class, and use it there.  I recommend going through a [C++/CLI Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx), as it will explain this fairly quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have managed types at global- or file-scope. Wrap the Connection object in an unmanaged (regular C++-style) class and create a global instance of that instead.

EDIT: After looking up the appropriate compiler mumbo-jumbo, here's what I came up with:

```
#include <vcclr.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace ONEAPI;

namespace Bot {
    class ConnectionWrapper {
    public:
        static gcroot<ONEAPI::Connection^> connection;
    };

    gcroot<ONEAPI::Connection^> ConnectionWrapper::connection = gcnew Connection(true);

    void InitializeBot() {
        ConnectionWrapper::connection->StartConnection(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to create a global instance of a dummy class if he puts it into a static field of said class.

Comment: Now it says "error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'connection' in an unmanaged 'ConnectionWrapper'

Comment: Try using gcroot<Connection> like the MSDN page for C3265 suggests.